# wiremock standalone server not starting using --print-all-network-traffic

Tags: wiremock

I am trying to run wiremock stand along server using command .

```
java -jar wiremock-1.57-standalone.jar --port=9090 --verbose --print-all-network-traffic
```

But it always give me exception .

```
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.util.MissingResourceException thrown from the 
UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

But after removing network command it starts fine.
Could you pleas help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was issue of old versions i updated jar file from 1.5 to 2.6